# Is there a way to detect the incoming call screen coming into foreground?

Tags: java, android

Within my app, I'd like to detect the incoming call screen coming on to the foreground. I do not want to detect an incoming call. What I need is to detect when an the incoming call screen comes into foreground.

Comment: What's the difference between "incoming call" and "incoming call screen"?

Comment: @codemonkey The incoming call screen doesn't always immediately come into the foregrounds. It takes a few ms.

Comment: detect the incoming call is the base, that's what the OS broadcast `to whom it may concern`, the default dialer app responses to this action by showing the income-screen, if that app delays for any reason, it's internal issue, you may not be able to detect.

Comment: @Yazan I read that it was possible to know which activity is in foreground. If that's possible, why can't knowing incoming call being in foreground be possible? Just curious.

Comment: what i know is (if you have the proper permissions) you can find out which APP is on foreground, not which activity, and though it may report that dialoerxxx is on top, but the screen still render or whatever it does that cause the delay